# Need help in using MySqlTransaction

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, .net-2.0

Hi all i would like to use `MySqlTransaction` in my requirement. Actually i am having a doubt regarding that i.e as per my requirement i will have to delete different values from database.

The process i am doing is as follows. Assume that i am having `2 EmpIDs`  where this `EmpID` will hold different values which may be multiple. I will store the corresponding values for that particular `EmpID` using `Dictionary` and then i will save them to a list corresponding to the EmpID.

Assume that i am having list element as follows

For `EmpID` `1` i will have `1,2`. I will check for the maximum value from the datbase in this list if exists i would like to delete this `EmpID` from the database.

For `EmpID` `2` i will have `1,2`. But in my database i will have `3` as maximum values. So this one fails . I would like to `rollback` the previously deleted item .

Is it possible to do with a `transaction` if so can any one help me in solving this

Sample i code

```
  if(findMax(lst,iEmpID)
  {
       obj.delete("storeprocname");   // this will occur when my list has maximum value
  }
 else
 {
     //Here i would like to rollback my previous one referring to the delete method in class file
 }
```

My sample code

```
if (findMaxPayPeriodID(lstPayPeriodID, iEmpIDs)) //Assume for the first time maxpayperiod exists and for the second time it fails how to rollback then
  {
    if (findSequence(lstPayPeriodID)) // Assume this is also true for first time
    {
      for (int ilstPayperiodID = 0; ilstPayperiodID < lstPayPeriodID1.Count; ilstPayperiodID++)
  {
      oAdmin.Payperiodnumber = (int)lstPayPeriodID1[ilstPayperiodID];
     for (int ilistPayYear = iPayYearcnt; ilistPayYear < lstPayYear1.Count; ilistPayYear++)
  {
      oAdmin.PayYear = (int)lstPayYear1[ilistPayYear];
      iPayYearcnt++;
      break;
   }
   for (int ilistDateTime = idtcnt; ilistDateTime < lstDateTime1.Count; ilistDateTime++)
  {
    idtcnt++;
    oAdmin.PaymentDate = lstDateTime1[ilistDateTime];
    break;
   }
       }
    if (oAdmin.deletePayRoll(oSqlTran))
    {
   oMsg.Message = "Deleted Sucessfully";
   oMsg.AlertMessageBox(out m_locallblMessage);
   Page.Controls.Add(m_locallblMessage);
   oAdmin.FedTaxID = ddlFedTaxID.SelectedValue;
   oAdmin.PayFrequency = ddlPaymentType.SelectedValue.ToString();
   mlocal_strStoredProcName = "uspSearchPayRoll";
   oAdmin.getPayRollDetails(out mlocal_ds, mlocal_strStoredProcName);
   //grdPayroll.Visible = true;
   grdPayroll.DataSource = mlocal_ds;
   grdPayroll.DataBind();
   if (mlocal_ds != null)
    {
       btnDelete.Visible = true;
     }
    else
    btnDelete.Visible = false;
    }
  lstPayPeriodID.Clear();
  lstDateTime.Clear();
  lstPayYear.Clear();
  iPayIDcnt = 0;
  iPayYearcnt = 0;
  idtcnt = 0;
   }
 else
   {
 rollback should be done
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't provide enough information - esp. since it seems that you will use a Stored Procedure for the delete operation all bets are off...

The only option I can think of is to make sure that you find first the maximum EmpId not from one list BUT from all lists first... then just check that against the DB and act accordingly...

This way the DB will only be hit twice (for the check and for the delete/Stored Procedure)... which is definetely better in terms of scaling etc.

Comment: So by using store procedure we can not do this na

Comment: Stored Procedures can implement their own transaction handling so in the best case this would be very vulnerable... thus: no - don't combine it the way you described it

Comment: Then how can i achieve my requirement i tried by writing bool in the function delete i have if true delete if not rollback but this doesn't work any help please

Comment: As I worte: first you need to find the max EmpId not only in one list but in all lists... then you determine whether the max of all lists is the max in the DB and if so then you call Stored Procedure to delete it...

Comment: Then i will miss the flow as per i need what i will have is i will have my EmpID as a dictionary key foreach key i will add the payid values to a list. For each and every employee i has to find out the maximum if exists i will go to my delete code by assigining the values

Comment: not sure that I understand you correctly - what is the goal you want to achieve ? it would perhaps if you showed some code esp. regarding the Dictionary/List stuff...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3316/discussion-between-user-and-yahia)